# Installation of epson scanner on ubuntu

Tags: scanner, software-installation

how do I install an epson scanner sx200 on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit? I have tried the simple scanner and it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar problem with an amd64 machine running Ubuntu Raring (Uberstudent actually). There are two files to be installed for your i386 machine (i.e. 32 bit) and one for printing.

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb iscan_2.29.2-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.3.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

According to epson's own [faq](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00002.html)  you should be sure to install the ltdl7 version and not the ltdl3 for the scanner. You will also likely need to be connected to the internet when you install as the printer deb file unpacks then runs apt-get to install alien and other files to convert the contained rpm file to deb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Download the right drive for your architecture for the printer and the scanner [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).  Once downloaded navigate to the folder where the file(s) were downloaded, and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

For both the printer, and scanner files.

Comment: thank you for trying. terminal just said there was no such file...i am getting so frustrated as keep trying anything Printer does test ok but will not print from computer.

Comment: Are you running 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu?  What file have you downloaded?

Comment: running 32 bit. ave downloaded deb file from epson.It did test print but nothing afterwards